# Saving foreign key user_id to posts table

Tags: php, laravel

I'm developing a laravel application with user and post model and i'm getting an error of:

```
Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value
```

I have set up relationships for both models. Post belongs to user and a user can have as many posts. The user_id is not being saved to the post table in the database.

Post Controller:

```
class PostController extends Controller

{
    public function postCreatePost(Request $request){

        $this->validate($request, [

            'body' => 'required'

        ]);

        $post = new Post([

           'body' => $request->input('body') 

        ]);

        $post->save();

        return redirect()->route('dashboard');

    }
```

Route:

```
Route::post('/createpost', [

    'uses' => 'PostController@postCreatePost',
    'as' => 'post.create'

]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify `user_id`:

```
$post = new Post([
    'body' => $request->input('body'),
    'user_id' => auth()->user()->id
]);
```

Or you could use relationship:

```
$user = auth()->user();
$user->posts()->create(['body' => $request->input('body')]);
```

Also, don't forget to add `user_id` to the `$fillable` array in the `Post` model.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is you are not giving a `user_id` when saving a post.

One solution is.

```
$post = new Post([

     'body' => $request->input('body'), 
     'user_id' => $your_use_id
]);
```

Comment: @Gayan you've forgotten to add a comma to the array.